# Multitouch screen needs two touch points

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-netbook, multi-touch

So, I got a netbook (Some weird China brand) and it has a multitouch screen. I got to installing Ubuntu Netbook 10.10 and I used the mouse and keyboard for that. When I wanted to try the touchscreen, at first it didn't seem to work, then I tried to multitouch, and this is what happens:

I put my finger on point A
I put my finger on point B, while still holding point A.

The cursor now jumps to the location on the screen where point A is touched. I can now use point A to drag the cursor ONLY when holding point B. I can use point B for clicking by tapping, but ONLY when holding point A at the place I want to click.

What is going on?

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a little more information on the make of your netbook and the touchscreen model? You may want to post the output of an `lspci` and/or `lsusb`.

Comment: well nothing seems wrong to me, i think that's how multitouch works on some screens

Comment: @uri: but not how multitouch works on any multitouch screens.

Comment: Have you fixed your problem? If so, please select an answer

Comment: @drnessie nope, none of the answers did the trick...

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, then please flag explaining that (as well as editing your question with any details you have).

Answer (score 1):

You certainly have found a bug, if you find an issue in the future, please do go directly to launchpad to report the issue. To report the issue from the desktop Hold [Alt] and press [F2], type into the box `ubuntu-bug ubuntu` and go through the process of reporting the issue.

Answer (score 1):

http://lii-enac.fr/en/architecture/linux-input/multitouch-ubuntu-howto.html

try that it fixed the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

I found same problem with you.
The Xinput Calibariton shows the touch screen brand : NAS 10.1
The NAS is Taiwanese company.  Full name is NAS Technologies Corp.

It seems that the muti-touch gesture has some problem to this touch screen.

One finger tap is not functioning well.  It is described as karthick87.
But when you drag the pointer on some icon with mouse; then one tap on it with finger.
It works then.  ???

Two fingers is OK.  I can use the scrolling bar etc.

Don't know how to try three fingers and four fingers.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem similar - no mouse jiggling, but the touchscreen wasnt working - I installed enac-drivers, a google search'll find it.

then, if you install ginn, you can get multitouch working.

I would also suggest easyStroke Gesture Recognition - great for creating touchscreen gestures!